# Help: Setting up Red5 on Ubuntu. Can't load install demo pages

Tags: video-streaming

I am attempting to set up a Red5 streaming server in order to live stream FLV files (not pseudo stream, not on-demand stream, but real live stream). I went through the usual process - install java, install ant, make the distribution, copy the ./dist/* to /usr/share/red5.

When I attempt to run the server with ./red5.sh, it appears to boot up correctly, the last line is something like "Bootstrap Completed". When I do a netstat -ant I notice that port 1935 is set to listen, but port 5080 is not open.

To my understanding if Red5 is operational then I should be able to visit http://localhost:5080/ or http://192.168.0.75:5080/ and see some sort of Red5 test page in order to install demos. Unfortunately neither work, and not surprisingly because port 5080 is *not* open.

I'm not certain what is causing the problem, I'm running it on Ubuntu 10.04. I do have an apache2 server running, but even if I turn it off prior to starting Red5 it doesn't change anything. The documentation for Red5 installation, operation and troubleshooting is beyond terrible, and I can't find anyone that seems to have the same issue I do. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let's go through the following link. Seems it may help us.

http://groups.google.com/group/red5interest/browse_thread/thread/77ae427d060f97df/6e2a69a9fed275f9

Answer (score 1):

Recently RED5 svn repository has got a major change. Now red5 is no longer tightly bound with tomcat. So, port 5080 is not up. One has to install tomcat plugin and configure accordingly as discussed in the above given link by me.

Hope you got an answer.

~Satya